# how to echo a PHP variable before it has been declared

Tags: php

I have a HTML button:

```
<button>Button Name</button>
```

below the button i have a div which i am requiring a file in:

```
<div id="my_div"><?php require_once 'file.php'; ?></div>
```

in the file.php file i have a PHP variable, i want to echo this variable on the button name `(Button Name var_here)`

but its not showing the variable as the variable is being declared after i echo it

is there any way round this?

Comment: my question is..But whyyyyiii?? why are u not trying it the other way i.e declare first and then echo. give a small hint

Comment: @Butterfruit think about why i haven't, because i need to require the file where i have. it will not display correctly if i do it the other way around

Comment: @Joren I know ;-) But remember there are use cases where `goto` makes sense in any language. Although in normal day-to-day use you will probably never see it.

Comment: It is better to remanage your code logic.

Comment: If you use a goto hell, then the variale has been declared... And not being used while undeclared.. I hope the OP does not use goto after reading it...

Comment: @RonniSkansing Why? It will fix the OPs problem >:)

Answer (score 8):

No. You can not echo out something that is not declared.

Answer (score 4):

Three suggestions:

1. Rearrange your HTML so that your button is below the declaration. Then use CSS to let your button appear above the `div`-container.
2. Change your php scripts so the declaration is done somewhere else before your button.
3. Use Jscript to change your button (p.e. like Amir Noori suggested).

Comment: how would i use css to re arrange the layout?

Comment: @charlie You really shouldn't

Comment: @charlie If you ask this question, please first start reading what css is and how it works, p.e. here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets. There are numerous ways to position elements on websites with css, I can't cover them all in here!

Answer (score 1):

you can add the variable with javascript

```
<button>Button Name</button>
<div><?php require_once('your_file.php'); ?></div>
<script> $('#btnID').html('<?php $var ?>')</script>
```

note:I don't think it is possible to use a variable before declaring it. with my code you actually using it after declaring  it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that you can't do the require before the button? If so, that's the real problem that you're trying to solve, because no, before you put the value in the variable, it isn't in the variable, and hence can't be echoed.

So to answer the question-behind-the-question, it's necessary to know more about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something about this design doesn't sit right with me, you usually include all your php up top, but I understand that for layout reasons you may want to go this way.

One way around it is to set this via javascript. This is a bit hacky (real hacky) but it would work. Use jQuery for ease of JS use after your include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  $('#my_div').text('<?php echo $my_var ?>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this now. In the required file rather than echoing the results creating a new variable ($var_display.= ...) then echoing $var_display under the HTML button

The file Is being required right at the top of the page